# taking the elements of array whitin a structure

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

here is my code, as you can see I used arrays of structures. The question is how should I take the arrays element by user directly? You can see below how the elements are given to the program before execution.

any help will be appericiated.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int x, y;
};

double interpolate(Data f[], int xi, int n)
{
    double P = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        double p= f[i].y;
        for (int j = 0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (j != i)
                p =p*(xi - f[j].x) / (f[i].x - f[j].x);
        }
        P += p;
    } 
    return P;
}

int main()
{
    Data f[] = { { 0,2 },{ 1,3 },{ 2,12 },{ 5,147 }};

    cout << "Value of f(3) is : " << interpolate(S, 3, 4) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to read input from user and save it in an array?

Comment: Do you want the user to input the numbers you assign to f[] in Data f[] = { { 0,2 },{ 1,3 },{ 2,12 },{ 5,147 }}; ?

Comment: Your code defines an uninitialized file scope variable `S` that is passed to the function `interpolate`. The main function defines and initializes an auto variable `f` that is not used. Clean up your code please.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- Yes mate

Comment: @Michael_H -- Yessssss

Comment: So your question is how to get input from a user? The description of where that data will eventually live is just ignorable context? (Try editing your question to be more precise about what exactly you want help with. If you know how to use [`cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), include some code showing that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int x, y;
};

double interpolate(Data f[], int xi, int n)
{
    double P = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        double p= f[i].y;
        for (int j = 0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (j != i)
                p =p*(xi - f[j].x) / (f[i].x - f[j].x);
        }
        P += p;
    } 
    return P;
}

int main()
{
    int input[8];

    cout << "Enter first value: \n";
    cin >> input[0];
    cout << "Enter second value: \n";
    cin >> input[1];
    cout << "Enter third value: \n";
    cin >> input[2];
    cout << "Enter fourth value: \n";
    cin >> input[3];
    cout << "Enter fifth value: \n";
    cin >> input[4];
    cout << "Enter sixth value: \n";
    cin >> input[5];
    cout << "Enter seventh value: \n";
    cin >> input[6];
    cout << "Enter eighth value: \n";
    cin >> input[7];

    Data f[] = {{input[0], input[1]}, {input[2], input[3]}, {input[4], input[5]}, {input[6], input[7]}};

    cout << "Value of f(3) is : " << interpolate(f, 3, 4) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```